# Help with geometry problem - don't have any idea

Tags: c++, geometry

I am preparing myself for programming competitions and i would like to know how can i solve this problem. I guess it's geometry problem, and it seems i can't get any ideas about solving it.

Here it is:

There is a yard in which there are wolves and sheep. In the yard there are also blocks which do not allow to pass. The wolves are represented with 'w' and the sheep with 's', while the blocks are with '#' and the space where everyone can move is '.' . So a possible input will look like:

```
8 8
.######.
#..s...#
#.####.#
#.#w.#.#
#.#.s#s#
#s.##..#
#.w..w.#
.######.
```

The 2 numbers above the yard are rows x columns.

As you can see, by this there can be formed sectors of different kind in the yard. Here are two sectors:

```
####
#.w#
####
#s.#
```

In the first one there is a wolf and in the second a sheep. Because they are placed in two different sectors (i.e. the wolf can't get to the sheep), he can't eat it. If they were in a same sector, the wolf would eat the sheep.

My question for you is this: Given an input like the ones above, how should i calculate how many sheep will survive ? How can i represent the 'yard' in c++ ? How should the algorithm looks like ? Are there any materials for understanding similar problems and issues ?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I provioded an answer below, but I must say that if a problem like this does not scream "GRAPH" at you, you have a LOT of preparation to do to be ready for any serious programming competition.

Comment: I agree with DVK. I have just returned home from the ICPC world finals, and if this problem were there it would be solved in about 4 minutes. I don't want to disuade you, but just be warned that you've got a lot of training ahead of you.

Comment: I would say anyone who immediately thinks "GRAPH" likes math-based over complicated solutions. To me it screams flood-fill.

Comment: For the question, is one wolf enough to kill all the sheep in a yard, or can each wolf only kill one sheep?

Comment: @phkahler, I hate to disappoint you, but flood fill IS a graph algorithm.

Comment: What is your definition of connectivity?  On a square grid, there's two definitions, both unsatisfactory.  Do you connect orthogonally only, or also by diagonals?  In other words, in your first input, are there one or two sectors?

Comment: @phkahler - on top of Polita's 2 valid points (it's inefficient to use flood fill, AND it is a kind of a graph algo anyway), it would take me personally MUCh faster to remember and implement connected component algo (basic BFS) whereas flood fill would take me much longer to remember how to do and to implement. As someone who actually competed in programming contests, I must say it is kind of an important criteria.

Comment: My apologies for the nasty tone I actually like mathy problems. I also see the connection to graphs, but it still screams flood fill because I think in grids and pixels more often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for here is to find the connected components of the graph, then you just need to count the number of wolves and sheep in each one.

```
using namespace std;

int w, h;
cin >> w >> h;
vector<string> grid(h);
for (int i = 0; i < h; ++i)
  cin >> grid[i];

vector< vector<bool> > seen(h, vector<bool>(w, false));
int survived = 0;
const int mx[] = {-1, 0, 1, 0}, my[] = {0, -1, 0, 1};

for (int i = 0; i < h; ++i)
  for (int j = 0; j < w; ++j)
    if (!seen[i][j] && grid[i][j] != '#')
    {
      int sheep = 0, wolves = 0;
      typedef pair<int, int> point;
      stack<point> s;
      s.push(point(i, j));

      while (!s.empty())
      {
        point p = s.top();
        int x = p.first, y = p.second;
        if (grid[x][y] == 'w') wolves++;
        if (grid[x][y] == 's') sheep++;
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; ++k)
        {
          int x2 = x + mx[k], y2 = y + my[k];
          if (x2<0 || x2>=h || y2<0 || y2>=w) continue;
          if (grid[x2][y2] == '#' || seen[x2][y2]) continue;
          s.push(point(x2, y2));
        }
      }
      survived += max(0, sheep - wolves);
    }

cout << "Surviving sheep = " << survived << endl;
```

Running time and memory usage is optimal at O(rows x columns).

Note that code is untested, but I believe this should work.

Comment: Heh... wouldn't it be swell if this was a guy posting LIVE from a programming competition and you just solved the problem for him? :)

Comment: How long did it take you to write this? (I'm kinda tempted to do a Perl implementation and see if I can beat your time once I'm off work :) )

Comment: Oh yeah, +1 for extra effory :)

Comment: I think it's not allowed internet access at programming competitions (it would be dumb to do so).

Comment: More likely you wrote his homework for him. (Admittedly advanced homework)

Comment: @DVK, it took me about 4-5 minutes to write that.

Comment: @ggg - they allow bathroom breaks. And people have smartphones these days.

Answer (score 3):

This problem is basically a problem of finding [connected sub-graphs (aka components)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29) for a given graph.

You can solve the problem by representing each "non-block" coordinate as a graph node, linking the 2 neighboring coordinates in a graph. Then find connected subgraphs using BFS (or any other algorithm suitable for the topic - I'm sure any web page or [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_Component_Labeling) on graph algos will have a list of assorted algorithms on that.

Once you have your subgraphs, just find which subgraphs  have zero wolves (by finding which subgraph each wolf coordinate is on), and count sheep in those subgraphs .

Hope this is enough for you to start.

Comment: Added a link to appropriate Wiki (connected component labeling is the term I was forgetting)

Comment: Yeah, I find each CPU cycle precious :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be to do a [flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) starting on each wolf. You can assume that each wolf will move (flood fill) the dots around him. After you flood fill starting from all the dots, any remaining sheep will survive.

In your example:

```
####
#.w#
####
#s.#
```

would fill to:

```
####
#fw#
####
#s.#
```

(I used f for the filled space), and the algorithm will stop, so `s` will survive.

Comment: Doing a flood fill on every wolf would not work in this problem. Imagine a 100 x 100 grid with a wolf on every square. You'd have to run 10000 flood fills, each filling the whole 10000 array, giving you 100,000,000 running time, which would not be accepted in the competition.

Comment: @poita incorrect. each flood fill should just overrun every square it gets to, besides the walls ofcourse. then you have at most 1 flood fill per square, which is very reasonable, and alot easier to implement. keep in mind - you have very little time to implement (AND DEBUG) a solution in this kind of competitions. I actually think flood filling is a way better solution in the given scenario.

Comment: @rmn, if you think that's a lot easier to implement then go ahead and prove me wrong. If you know anything about algorithms then you'll be well aware that the only difference between a DFS (what I suggested) and a BFS/flood-fill (what you suggested) is the fact that DFS uses a stack and BFS uses a queue (go ahead, change the stack in my code to a queue and it will be a BFS). Therefore, it takes the EXACT same amount of time to implement, right down to the very character.

Answer (score -1):

maybe try thinking of the yard as a group of sectors.  when creating a sector, if there is a wolf in it, remove all sheep.  Now the only challenge is representing a sector, which seems much more manageable.

Answer (score -1):

Consider using the logic of [flood filling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367226/flood-fill-algorithms) algorithms.

Answer (score -1):

Doesn't look like a geometry problem to me. I would solve it with the [Flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) algorithm

Fill every area with a unique number. Then, for every number you filled an area with, find out how many sheep and how many wolves are adjacent to that number. The only surviving sheep are those that are adjacent to a number k that no wolves are adjacent to.

You can represent the matrix in C++ as a matrix of chars: char A[maxrows][maxcols]. However, to use flood fill, I would use a matrix of ints, because you might have more areas than the max value of a char.

Comment: Or use a BFS algorithm like this: add every wolf in a queue. Then when you extract a wolf, you mark each of its adjacent positions. When you hit (heheh) a sheep, decrement the number of sheep left alive. This would be O(lines x cols). Simple and optimal.

Answer (score -1):

Is this a time-limited competition?  E.g., one where your score is a function of the number of programs solved in a given time?

For these I would recommend a simple approach based on two things:

- Represent the data as a 2D array
- Determine when sheep and wolves share a sector by searching connectivity, using something like a flood-fill algorithm from each wolf.  I would recommend starting from the wolves and "killing off" sheep when you reach them.  After you do this for each wolf, any remaining sheep in the data structure survive.

The key in the time-limited competitions is to come up with a simple solution that's quick to program.  Modern computers are extremely fast.  Don't think about geometric algorithms unless you need to be able to handle vast data sets, just think how could I throw computation at the problem to solve it easily.

While I thought about this several other people suggested flood-filling, so this is somewhat redundant.

Comment: Of course, the "correct" algorithmic solution to a problem like this is determine the connected components, and then count the number of sheep that are in connected components that contain no wolves.

Answer (score -1):

1.Copy the wolves to all adjacent cells where is legal for the wolve to move. Overwrite anything that is not a wall.
2.Count the remaining sheeps.