# Filling a specific region of a shape containing another shape

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing

In Winforms application, i am doing 2D drawing.
for example, when i try fill a rectangle, that contains a circle. i want only region outside of circle should be filled with the specified color.
i tried but entire rectangle is getting filled.

Comment: Please add some more detail. Exactly what code did you try?

Comment: Yes, we could use more detail, but if this is a helpful idea: you could paint the rectangle first, then draw the circle filled with whatever background/underlying color afterward.

Comment: Is this question relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/q/367226/10468

Answer (score 3):

Just try this to get the desired output. Open a windows forms and add a button. In the button click event, just add this code:

```
Region rgn = new Region(new Rectangle(50, 50, 200, 150));
System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath path = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
path.AddEllipse(60, 60, 100, 100);
rgn.Exclude(path);
Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
g.FillRegion(Brushes.Blue, rgn);
```

"rgn.Exclude(Path)" will help you to paint the rectangle excluding the circle inside it.

Comment: These lines of code helped me a lot. Thank you very much.