# How Scanline based 2d rendering engines works?

Tags: graphics

Will you please provide me a reference to help me understand how scanline based rendering engines works?
I want to implement a 2D rendering engine which can support region-based clipping, basic shape drawing and filling with anti aliasing, and basic transformations (Perspective, Rotation, Scaling). I need algorithms which give priority to performance rather than quality because I want to implement it for embedded systems with no fpu.

Comment: Do you mean GPU (Graphics Processing Unit) or FPU (Floating-Point Unit)?

Comment: I mean No GPU and No FPU just ARM926EJS RISC Processor with 200mhz and 32MB SDram running at 100Mhz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm probably showing my age, but I still love my copy of [Foley, Feiner, van Dam, and Hughes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201848406) (The White Book).

Jim Blinn had a great column that's available as a book called [Jim Blinn's Corner: A Trip Down the Graphics Pipeline](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558603875).

Both of these are quited dated now, and aside from the principles of 3D geometry, they're not very useful for programming today's powerful pixel pushers.

OTOH, they're probably just perfect for an embedded environment with no GPU or FPU!

Comment: Hi mtnygard,
  I bought (Foley, Feiner, van Dam, and Hughes) Book. Thank for suggation.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a good series of articles by Chris Hecker that covers software rasterization:

http://chrishecker.com/Miscellaneous_Technical_Articles

And here is a site that talks about and includes code for a software rasterizer.  It was written for a system that does not have an FPU (the GP2X) and includes source for a fixed point math library.

http://www.trenki.net

Comment: Well, Links are preety good for 3d rendering, But I want to implement a 2D renderer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the rest, but I can help you with fast scaling and 2D rotation for ARM (written in assembly language).  Check out a demo:

http://www.modaco.com/content/smartphone-software-games/291993/bbgfx-2d-graphics-library-beta/

L.B.

Comment: Hi LB,
  I don't found Rotation and scaling code in that link. It is blank. I am eager to know that how can you rotate any bitmap.

Comment: The link is a post on Modaco about a 2D graphics engine I'm working on.  It includes fast ARM assembly language to rotate 2D bitmaps in real time.  Here is the link to the demo application (Windows Mobile) and sample code:

www.bitbanksoftware.com/private/bbgfx_demo.zip

Comment: Bitbank I can't find assembly optimized functions in the ZIP file, Will you please check and tell me where they are?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry Sunny, but the source code is not free.  The point of passing you the link is to allow you to run the demo code and see if it is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi Bitbank,
  I am running embedded-linux. So I can not test .exe file. Have you executable for linux?

Thanks Sunny.

Comment: I don't work with embedded linux.  contact me directly to continue this discussion.